# Discord API keeps saying Invalid redirect_uri

Tags: discord

[image]I don't know why this is happening. I've tried out everything.My code works fine and i get a popup on discord login after that I get error Invalid OAuth URL.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must register the return URL in the Discord Developer Portal Application settings. The link looks like this https://discord.com/developers/applications//oauth2.

You even have to do this for developing, e.g. add `https://localhost:5000` as a return URL, if your local development server runs at localhost port 5000.

Answer (score 1):

Have you filled in the redirect url here...

[image: discord redirect url entry]

Comment: Yes I have filled

Comment: should it be https://localhost:3000 or https://localhost:3000/auth/callback for me as I have my auth under these routes